# How to make a Script to switch on/off wifi till internet starts working?

Tags: wireless, scripts

I'm unable to fix my wifi internet connection issue, so I thought instead of manually switching on/off wifi and reloading webpage until internet start working if it is possible through script?

Comment: You could switch on and off with the command `nmcli radio wifi on` and `nmcli radio wifi off` with some sleep between, and you could ping some address to see if it works, but really I don't think that this a good procedure to solve connection problems.

Comment: See https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic.git - Watch for (WiFi) network going down, then do a user-specified thing to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
while :
do
  echo restarting network manager...
  service network-manager restart
  echo sleeping for 30 seconds...
  sleep 30
  echo trying to access a web page...
  wget -O /dev/null vecka.nu && exit 0
done
```

Comment: how to run this as admin. I have to repeatedly type the password for running network service

Comment: Run it using sudo?